# Loop through Visible Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is to refer all worksheets in the current workbook in a numeric order
The code works fine with the only problem being that the code as whole also includes hidden worksheets.
i.e. C_Shs also counts hidden worksheets, and hidden worksheets are also included in the loop and referred accordingly. The code is as follows

```
Sub Straight_Refer()
Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
Dim L_Col As Long, C_Shs As Long, r As Long, Initial As Variant

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If sh.Visible Then
C_Shs = C_Shs + 1
End If
Next

Initial = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Write initials of your WP", Title:="Initials of WP", Type:=2)

For r = 1 To C_Shs
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
   If sh.Visible Then
   Worksheets(r).range("E2:AZ2").ClearContents
     L_Col = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(r).Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(r).Cells(2, L_Col + 1).Value = "<" & Initial & "/" & r & ">"
 End If
 Next
Next r
```

The problem with this code is that it skips the number of the hidden sheet
i.e. sheet3 should be "3" and sheet4 should be "4".
If sheet3 is hidden, i want sheet4 to become "3" however with this code sheet4 remains "4"

Comment: What do you mean by "skipping a number"? I don't see you manually incrementing the loop variable, so it would increment with the loop as normal... unless i'm not understanding something... maybe you can update your question to include the `Visible` check where you have tried using it? It seems to be missing from your post. Also, fixing the indenting would make it much easier to read.

Comment: edited it accordingly

Comment: Why do you need a number? simply use the `sh` object. `If sh.Visible Then sh.range("E2:AZ2").ClearContents`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to count how many sheets are visible first. Just use the `sh` loop and get `r` from the sheet index.

```
Sub Straight_Refer()
  Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
  Dim L_Col As Long, C_Shs As Long, r As Long, Initial As Variant
  
  Initial = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Write initials of your WP", Title:="Initials of WP", Type:=2)
  
  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     If sh.Visible Then
       sh.Range("E2:AZ2").ClearContents
       L_Col = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
       r = sh.Index
       sh.Cells(2, L_Col + 1).Value = "<" & Initial & "/" & r & ">"
     End If
  Next

End Sub
```

This assumes you need the `r` variable for something else in your code that you are not showing... You can actually remove the `r` variable altogether in this example if you don't.

Also, if you need to use that count of visible sheets somewhere else, you can use a variable for that as well and increment that inside of your `If` statement too.

---

**Note:**

This is not part of your question, but will also need to be addressed.

`Find` returns a `Range` object (not a `Long`), which can be `Nothing` if no results were found.

You should always save the `Find` results to a `Range` or `Variant` object first, and then check to make sure it has actually found something before doing something with the results. Then you can check the `Address` or `Column` property of the result `Range` object to get the column number.